# What are the differences between these functions when used for NMaximize?

Tags: functions, function-construction, mathematical-optimization, functional-style

In short, the question is how to construct the function you want to optimize?

```
link3 = {679, 531, 379, 272, 198, 143, 99, 67, 46, 32, 22, 14, 9, 5, 3, 1};
klink3 = 20;
B1997 = {14, 10, 6, 3, 3, 6, 2, 3, 2, 1, 1, 1, 0, 3, 2, 0, 3, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1};
kB1997 = 50;

mylik[data_, kdata_] := Block[{K, mypdf, fj, pj, loglik},
    K = kdata;
    mypdf = ProbabilityDistribution[
        Binomial[K, j]*(w*p^j*(1 - p)^(K - j) + (1 - w)*
        Beta[alpha + j, beta + K - j]/Beta[alpha, beta]), {j, 0, K, 1}
    ];
    pj = Probability[pj == Range[0, K], pj \[Distributed] mypdf];
    fj = Prepend[PadRight[data, K], f0];
    loglik = LogGamma[Total[fj] + 1] - Total[LogGamma[fj + 1]] + fj.Log[pj]
];

mylik2[data_, kdata_, f0_?NumericQ, w_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ, 
    alpha_?NumericQ, beta_?NumericQ] := 
    Block[{K, mypdf, fj, pj, loglik},
    K = kdata;
    mypdf = ProbabilityDistribution[
        Binomial[K, j]*(w*p^j*(1 - p)^(K - j) 
        + 
        (1 - w)* Beta[alpha + j, beta + K - j]/Beta[alpha, beta]), {j, 0, K, 1}];
    pj = Probability[pj == Range[0, K], pj \[Distributed] mypdf];
    fj = Prepend[PadRight[data, K], f0];
    loglik = LogGamma[Total[fj] + 1] - Total[LogGamma[fj + 1]] + fj.Log[pj]
];


cons = {f0 > 0, alpha > 0, beta > 0, 0 < p < 1, 0 < w < 1};
pars = {f0, p, w, alpha, beta};
```

Using different ways of constructing the likelihood function,

```
OptMethod = "RandomSearch"

NMaximize[{mylik[link3, klink3], cons}, pars, Method -> {OptMethod, "SearchPoints" -> Automatic}] // AbsoluteTiming
NMaximize[{mylik[link3, klink3], cons}, pars, Method -> {OptMethod, "SearchPoints" -> 100}] // AbsoluteTiming
NMaximize[{mylik[B1997, kB1997], cons}, pars, Method -> {OptMethod, "SearchPoints" -> Automatic}] // AbsoluteTiming
NMaximize[{mylik[B1997, kB1997], cons}, pars, Method -> {OptMethod, "SearchPoints" -> 100}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Just under 10 seconds.

```
NMaximize[{mylik2[link3, klink3, f0, w, p, alpha, beta], cons}, pars, Method -> {OptMethod, "SearchPoints" -> Automatic}] // AbsoluteTiming
NMaximize[{mylik2[link3, klink3, f0, w, p, alpha, beta], cons}, pars, Method -> {OptMethod, "SearchPoints" -> 100}] // AbsoluteTiming
NMaximize[{mylik2[B1997, kB1997, f0, w, p, alpha, beta], cons}, pars, Method -> {OptMethod, "SearchPoints" -> Automatic}] // AbsoluteTiming
NMaximize[{mylik2[B1997, kB1997, f0, w, p, alpha, beta], cons}, pars, Method -> {OptMethod, "SearchPoints" -> 100}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

Almost a minute using the second method.

It seems there is clearly a difference. So what are the general rules to construct a function for optimization?

Comment: Some of the timing is overhead. For example when I removed the NumericQ tests in mylik2 it runs as fast as mylik

Comment: But a lot of the time people are telling me I should leave ?NumericQ in the function as that is the "proper" way to write a function? It also ensures wired behavior when using optimization, such as "the function is not a real number at ........", sometimes, NMAximize does not replace the parameters using their numerical values.

Comment: I seriously doubt repeated calls to `NumericQ` is the problem.  It is likely that without `NumericQ` `NMaximize` is able to come up with an optimized expression for your function symbolically which it caches. With `NumericQ` it can't optimize/evaluate the expression symbolically.