# The problem (time) caused by ?NumericQ

Tags: function-construction, numerics, mathematical-optimization, functional-style, numerical-value

In [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69406/what-are-the-differences-between-these-functions-when-used-for-nmaximize?), I asked a related (similar) question. Using `?NumericQ` seems have slowed down the entire calculation.

But I now have a more serious problem:

```
B1998 = {14, 9, 7, 4, 2, 4, 4, 0, 4, 2, 0, 1, 0, 3, 0, 3, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1};
kB1998 = 50;

myBBBlik[data_, kdata_, f0_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ, w_?NumericQ, 
    mu_?NumericQ, theta_?NumericQ] :=
    Block[
    {K, fj, pj, loglik},
    K = kdata;
    fj = Prepend[PadRight[data, K], f0];
    pj = Table[
    (w*p^j*(1 - p)^(K - j)
    + (1 - w)
    *NProduct[mu + r*theta, {r, 0, j - 1}]
    *NProduct[1 - mu + r*theta, {r, 0, K - j - 1}]
    /NProduct[1 + r*theta, {r, 0, K - 1}]
    )*Binomial[K, j], {j, 0, K}];

    loglik = 
    LogGamma[Tr[fj] + 1] - Tr[LogGamma[fj + 1]] + Tr[fj*Log[pj]];
    loglik
];

NMaximize[{myBBBlik[B1998, kB1998, f0, p, w, mu, theta], f0 > 0, 0 < p < 1, 0 < w < 1, 0 < mu < 1, theta > 0}, {f0, p, w, mu, theta}] // AbsoluteTiming


{170.991900, {-49.4846, {f0 -> 0.0602345, p -> 0.0478278, w -> 0.522311, mu -> 0.259876, theta -> 0.11778}}}
```

More than three minutes.

```
myBBBlik2[data_, kdata_] :=
    Block[
    {K, fj, pj, loglik},
    K = kdata;
    fj = Prepend[PadRight[data, K], f0];
    pj = Table[
    (w*p^j*(1 - p)^(K - j)
    + (1 - w)
    *Product[mu + r*theta, {r, 0, j - 1}]
    *Product[1 - mu + r*theta, {r, 0, K - j - 1}]
    /Product[1 + r*theta, {r, 0, K - 1}]
    )*Binomial[K, j], {j, 0, K}];

    loglik = 
    LogGamma[Tr[fj] + 1] - Tr[LogGamma[fj + 1]] + Tr[fj*Log[pj]];
    loglik
];

NMaximize[{myBBBlik2[B1998, kB1998], f0 > 0, 0 < p < 1, 0 < w < 1, 0 < mu < 1, theta > 0}, {f0, p, w, mu, theta}] // AbsoluteTiming

{12.480022, {-49.4846, {f0 -> 0.0602345, p -> 0.0478278, w -> 0.522311, mu -> 0.259876, theta -> 0.11778}}}
```

Note that in the second case, I have change from `NProduct` to `Product`.

So maybe I should keep leaving the parameters out of the function?
But then in [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/61023/numerical-integration-with-nintegrate) (a different model), it seems that sometimes, we just have to put the parameters in the function, as their arguments AND use `?NumericQ`.

Now the extreme case:

```
NMaximize[{myBBBlik[B1998, kB1998, f0, p, w, mu, theta], f0 > 0, 0 < p < 1, 0 < w < 1, 0 < mu < 1, theta > 0}, {f0, p, w, mu, theta}, Method -> "RandomSearch"] // AbsoluteTiming
```

I have added `Method -> "RandomSearch"`, I waited and waited,
and waited,

In this case, it seems that `?NumericQ` has made it "impossible" to optimize????

[image]

Note the time stamp in the screenshot. I aborted it after nearly half an hour.

Why does `?NumericQ` cause so much trouble??

What's the best way to construct function for `NMaximize`?? Do we leave variables out of the function, or in the function as arguments?

Comment: Could you perhaps try to come up with a MWE to demonstrate the problem? At the moment the question seems quite localized.

Comment: @YvesKlett I am not sure how "minimal" you would like it to be? I have given a function that I want to optimize, and compared with a variation of the function. And showed the timing.

Comment: You might get better answers if your question and code are concise and address a general problem. At the moment,  parsing your code is not entirely straightforward.

Comment: @YvesKlett Are you referring to all the code in those posts? If you only try out the three pieces of the code in this post. The problem should be obvious? Using `NumericQ` is slowing down the calculation.

Comment: YvesKlett's comment is this: can you find a simple situation in which the same effect occurs. For example, if this problem only occurs when there are 3 `Products` times a `Binomial`, it is not of general interest. If it happens for other, more generic and simple combinations of functions, then it may be of general interest.

Comment: @bills thanks for the clarification.  Happy XMas!

Comment: @bills Yes, I think I got what you mean. However, say if I find a simpler example, where using `?NumericQ` only makes a difference of couple of seconds, I dont think I would be worried too much. This is just like saying, ok something works for a simple example, then I dont worry about the complicate real practical example. In this case, what I am presenting here, is what happens in practice, when MMA is being used for real application on real dataset. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @YvesKlett Happy Christmas! I do appreciate you guys taking time reading the post!

Comment: It often happens that by searching for a simple example, you can discover the essence of what is causing the problem. Is it because of the form of the function you are maximizing? Is it the number of variables being maximized over? Is it the ranges of the parameters? If you can narrow this down, you may find that you can state the problem in a compelling manner.

Comment: You are welcome - switching over to holiday mode now though over here ;-)

Comment: @bills To be honest, I dont know what is causing the problem. I created this post focusing on `NumericQ` because someone in the comment mentioned a lot of the timing is being used on `NumericQ`. I had investigated the ways to construct the function in a different post, but no answer was posted. FYI, the `pj`s are from a density function of Binomial and a betabinomial , where the three `Products` is just a different way of expressing the density of the betabinomial. I have tried various ways (even using built-in function) to construct the function, but the outcome was just not good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that you have an **inefficient inner loop** when you use myBBBlik.  Every time you call myBBBlik, it takes a certain amount of time to calculate the result (on my computer, about 1/2 second of mucking around because your likelhood function is a bit complex).

But myBBBlik2 creates an algebraic expression once (?or twice?) and can substitute the numerical values in relatively quickly.  So the "Prepend, PadRight, Table" stuff is skipped.

To demonstrate this, add the following to your code in both myBBBlik and myBBBlik2:

```
Dynamic@callCounter
callCounter = 1;
```

Inside the Block, add

```
...
Block[
{K, fj, pj, loglik},
callCounter = callCounter + 1;
K = kdata;
...
```

You will see that in myBBBlik, callCounter is incremented roughly every 1/2 second, as myBBBlik is called about that often.  But when you use myBBBlik2, it is called only twice, because myBBBlik2 has symbolic output.